# Refresh a snowflake database

Tags: database, refresh, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have 2 snowflake environments (non-prod and prod) . Is there a way to refresh a Prod database into non-prod environment and/or look into automating this process.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to replicate the prod environment at one point in time to a test environment so you can work with real data there.

That is easily done with the `CLONE DATABASE` command but requires the prod and test databases to be within the same account.  With Snowflake, you should keep all your environments in the same account, but separate them with different roles and possibly different users.

The `CLONE DATABASE` command can be repeated at any time to catch up with production.

Answer (score 0):

By Environment, you mean two separate accounts or two separate databases ?

I am not sure about meaning of "*refreshing the data*" but if :

1. **Its two separate database** : You can create views in non-prod database pointing to PROD database that way always looking at latest set of data.
2. **If its two separate env** : You can use ***Sharing*** feature of SNOWFLAKE which helps in data sharing between separate account.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that cloning individual tables with copy grants allows you to copy the grants on those objects so one does not need to re-apply role permissions.
I use a stored procedure to run all of my object cloning from Prod-> Uat -> Dev etc.
This is effective for data, however if you are making schema changes on the lower environments, this may not be the best solution.  Copying from source to target (prod to uat). Here is some sample code, modify it to suit your needs. 
You can add as many tables as you need. Just repeat the code within the $$ javascript $$ block.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE public.clone_table_objects(SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR,DESTINATION_DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$  
  table1 = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
      "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  " + DESTINATION_DATABASE_NAME + ".schema1.table1  COPY GRANTS CLONE "+ SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME + ".schema1.table1;"
       } );
  table2 = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
      "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  " + DESTINATION_DATABASE_NAME + ".schema1.table2    COPY GRANTS CLONE "+ SOURCE_DATABASE_NAME + ".schema1.table2;"
       } );
  $$;
```

Execute the procedure.
CALL public.clone_table_objects('prod_db'::VARCHAR,'uat_db'::VARCHAR);